# When to Start process from service ( the process will be a service ) or start it from startup?

Tags: c#, windows-services

What is actually the different between those start processes ? 
I know the simple differences ( code different, service can start and stop from the windows service manager, ext. )

When i need to do the process as service and when i will prefer to start the process from the start-up ( in case i need to make the process start when the OS starts )

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking the differences between services and the StartUp folder?

Services run when the computer is on and stay running.

Programs in the Startup folder run when someone logs in.